# May onLocationChanged never be called?

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which finds the location of the phone with SMS. I use a sms broadcast receiver and when the right SMS comes in, acquire a wakelock then initiate the locating service which request location updates from both GPS and NETWORK. On the first **onLocationChanged** I send the position to requester, stop the service and release the lock.

I want to know does android always call **onLocationChanged**? or maybe when it can't find the location of device (device is indoor for example), it's not called never?

It's very important that this function is called , because if it's not the lock is not released until the battery is empty. In that situation, is there any other way to finalize the service?

Something else, Dose location service needs power lock at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it can't get a GPS lock it will never call onLocationChanged.  Unless you want to keep the screen on I don't think you need to hold a wakelock though-  I believe the GPS system will call you when the phone is woken up.

Comment: I believe as soon as the broadcast receiver ends the device goes to sleep again and service doesn't get started even. I dont acquire full lock, just a partial lock which keeps the cpu on. Is there any other method which tells that android couldn't find the location? I see such a thing in some apps like instagram.

Comment: You can set an alarm and timeout your request.  You can also try implementing onStatusChanged-  it tells you when you lose or gain GPS synch, but I don't know off the top of my head if it's called immediately.  If not you can probably check by calling getGPSStatus on locationManager.

Comment: I set a timer to call it off after five mins no matter it was successful or not.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan, could you elaborate a bit more on "can't get a GPS lock"? Are you talking about `mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` returning false?

Comment: No.  I mean if it can't find enough satelites to give a GPS location.  For example, indoors or underground.